# How to evaluate multiple OR'd conditions in COUNTIFS (or similar) row-by-row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

Consider the following sample data.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |

Separately, the count of A that is less than 5 is `=COUNTIF(A1:A5, "<5")` -> 4, and that for B is `=COUNTIF(B1:B5, "<5")` -> 3.

I know if I want the count of rows where A **and** B are < 5, I can use COUNTIFS: `=COUNTIFS(A1:A5, "<5", B1:B5, "<5")` -> 2 because COUNTIFS evaluates conditions row-by-row. However, I can't figure out an elegant way to get the count of rows where A **or** B is < 5.

Using the sample data, the *answer should be 5*. So far I've tried:

- `=COUNTIF(A1:A5, "<5") + COUNTIF(B1:B5, "<5")` -> 7, because the cells aren't treated as rows. This just counts the number of cells <5.
- `=SUM(IF(A1:A5 < 5, 1, 0), IF(B1:B5 < 5, 1, 0))` -> 7, does the same thing as the above.
- `=SUM(IF(OR(A1:A5 < 5, B1:B5 < 5), 1, 0))` -> 1, because the cells are not treated as rows, and the OR returns just one value combining the results of each cell condition. Evaluates to 1 if any cell is <5, 0 if none are.

I have found one functioning solution which uses the [addition theorem of probability](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Addition-Theorem-of-Probability_39444/?adlt=strict) (see my answer for that), but I'd like a way to do this that's easier to read and scale, if possible. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just curious if anyone has an answer for this that works in Sheets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Excel 365 you can use FILTER function:

`=COUNT(FILTER(A1:A5,(A1:A5<5) + (B1:B5<5)))`

separating conditions by * will act as AND, while separating them by + will work as OR.

Comment: I like this one as it can be used on full column ranges (e.g. A:A) without needing to account for headers or blanks, can scale easily to more columns, and can be used with string comparisons `=COUNT(FILTER(A:A,(A:A<5) + (B:B<5) + (C:C="test")))`.

Comment: Yes but each time you use a full column reference you are forcing each iteration of the formula to calculate over more than a million cells, which is potentially a huge overhead (imagine only having data as far as row 1000, say). The `FILTER` function does not employ implicit detection of the last-used cell within the ranges passed; instead, it calculates over all cells within the ranges passed.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematically `x OR y` is equivalent to `x + y >= 1` with x and y being boolean values. And in Excel to convert from bool to int we typically use `--`. So the either of the below will work

```
=SUM(--(IF(A1:A5 < 5, 1, 0) + IF(B1:B5 < 5, 1, 0) > 0))
=SUM(--(--(A1:A5 < 5) + --(B1:B5 < 5) > 0))
```

It can even be shortened to

```
=SUM(--(-(A1:A5 < 5) + -(B1:B5 < 5) < 0))
=SUM(--(-(A1:A5 < 5) - (B1:B5 < 5) < 0))
```

Answer (score 4):

Not the prettiest solution and it gets very messy when you have more than two conditions, but one can use the [addition theorem of probability](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Addition-Theorem-of-Probability_39444/?adlt=strict) `P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)` to calculate the requested count:

- `=COUNTIF(A1:A5, "<5") + COUNTIF(B1:B5, "<5") - COUNTIFS(A1:A5, "<5", B1:B5, "<5")` -> 5

Comment: For counting (rather than probability) it's usually referred to as the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 2):

If the columns in question are contiguous, then a more flexible and scalable solution is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(MMULT(N(A1:B5<5),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:B5)))>0))
```

Or, for O365:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N(A1:B5<5),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:B5)))>0))
```